# "vacation" versus "a vacation"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

When is it appropriate to use ***a*** with ***vacation***?

For instance, I found these examples in the dictionaries:

> You look tired — you should *take **a vacation***.
>
> When are you *taking **vacation*** this year?

What's the difference between the two sentences? Why one of them uses ***a vacation*** and the other simply ***vacation***?

And then, when do you say *go on vacation* and *go on **a** vacation*?

(Examples from the COCA)

> A: Where do you *go on vacation*?
>
> B: The beach. I love to travel, but I don't get to much.

and

> A: Kids, we're about to *go on **a** vacation*!
>
> B: Hooray! We're going to Disney World!

I'm so confused!

Comment: I could be wrong, but the sentence containing "take vacation this year" could be talking of the most important vacation. For example, with 25 days of paid vacation, I could take a one-day vacation five times, and then take vacation and go visit my American friend, staying there 20 work-days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### To take...

For me, this one always uses "a".

> To take **a** vacation.

However, if you change it to a noun (gerund) it can lose the "a":

> Taking vacations is my favorite past-time.

I speak American English, so, it may be that "to take vacation" doesn't sound wrong to British English speakers.

#### To go on...

Both with and without "a" sound fine, but possibly with a small difference.

> I went on a vacation last week. Where did you go?
>
> I went on vacation last week. Oh, that explains why you weren't in the office.

To me, "to go on **a** vacation" seems more exciting than without **a**. I would use the second version, if I do not intend to tell people where I went, but rather, just want to tell them I was gone (although they might still ask anyway).

The perspective is a little different.

> I went on a vacation to Italy. (the place you went to)
>
> I went on vacation from work. (the place you left)

But you could also say,

> I went on vacation to the Bahamas.

#### To be on...

Same as **To go on...**, the article just changes the emphasis a bit.

> Hello, this is XYZ Management Services. How can I help you?
>
> Could you transfer me to Susan?
>
> I'm sorry, she's **on vacation** till next week, do you need help with your account?

Comment: Actually, the sentence _When are you **taking vacation** this year?_ was taken from an American dictionary, namely the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/vacation). Dialectal difference?

Comment: I speak AmE as well, and you are right that *taking vacation* as in "I am taking vacation at the beach this year" is not idiomatic, but "I am taking **my** vacation at the beach" is perfectly fine. And so is the question, "When are you taking vacation this year?" when asked by my boss- to which I might answer, "I'm taking July 1st through July 16th" and December 9th through the end of the year."

Comment: Xantix, it does sound wrong from a British perspective because, British people don't use the word "vacation". We use the word *holiday*.

Comment: I think that MW example is just plain *wrong*. Google Books has just 7 instances of [he is taking vacation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+taking+vacation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and four of those are duplicates. Compare that to 1790 instances of [he is taking **a** vacation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+taking+a+vacation%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is the only version that seems acceptable to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In general I agree, but I think Jim has a point with "When are you taking vacation this year?" in a *work* context; I hear this often, with *vacation* being a shortened reference to *your vacation time/days*. In AmE, anyway. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: Usages like this can't really be labelled "right" or "wrong" - it's just that in this specific case, one form is overwhelmingly more common than the other (particularly in the UK, I suspect). What I really meant was I think it was wrong of MW to use the less common form in their example, but I didn't express that at all well.